# How to use hotkey,off in #IfWinActive section

Tags: autohotkey

I am using the following code:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
4::Send,4
5::
    Hotkey,4,off
;~  do something
    Hotkey,4,on
    Return
#IfWinActive
```

but it generates this error:

```
Prompt Error:  Nonexistent hotkey variant (IfWin).
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by using `4` to send `4` - it seems redundant.

I tried it like this.
pushing 4 will send 6, and pushing 5 will send 4.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
{
    4::Send,6
    5::
        Hotkey,4,off
        send, 4
        Hotkey,4,on
    Return
}
```

The idea here is that the brackets encase the entire function within the IfWinActive.  If notepad isn't active, nothing at all happens.

Comment: If the sole purpose is preventing hotkeys from triggering themselves, you can simply use the [$ modifier](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).