# Creating a conditional for autohotkey - Do not send anything if box is open

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, autohotkey

Well, I have this autohotkey script I wrote and it looks like this:

```
^1::SendInput t/accepthelp 1{enter}
^2::SendInput t/accepthelp 2{enter}
^3::SendInput t/accepthelp 3{enter}
^4::SendInput t/accepthelp 4{enter}
^5::SendInput t/accepthelp 5{enter}
^6::SendInput t/accepthelp 6{enter}
^7::SendInput t/accepthelp 7{enter}
^8::SendInput t/accepthelp 8{enter}
^9::SendInput t/accepthelp 9{enter}
```

This is meant for SAMP and it works pretty good. **t** is the key that triggers the input box to open in the game.

What I need to do is this: If I open the box manually in game (I press **t**) and then I randomly press the hotkeys, I don't want them to send anything! IF the input box is on the screen - hotkeys should be void during that time; They only should work when the input box is hidden/closed.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you not [looked at the docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm)?  Look at `IfWinActive` - that page includes `IfWinNotActive` (if you look closely enough), which is what you need.

Also, [there is an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871390/how-to-use-hotkey-off-in-ifwinactive-section) of how you can use it with your hotkeys.

*(I should get a point for fetching you the link to the docs)*

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I actually couldn't get anything from the link you provided. I still couldn't figure out how to prevent sending a text message if the input box is open - IfWinActive has another purpose I think.

Comment: No, you use look at `IfWinActive` in the docs (I linked it), you will see that there is `IfWinNotActive` - *which is what you need*.  The other link shows you the format to use with the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

As this is for a game with its own client, ifwin will not help with ingame boxes or windows.

for something like that your best bet maybe to use a form of pixel or image search

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

Hope it helps